# How do I get maximum supported point size in Metal

Tags: ios, swift, graph, metal

I'm rendering a particle system using `Metal` on iOS device. I'm constrained to use Normal shaders instead of compute functions. So I'm using `MTLPrimitiveTypePoint` for drawing particles.

While following one of the Open GL code for reference, I found that you can query the maximum point size using:

```
float pointSizeRange[2];
glGetFloatv(GL_ALIASED_POINT_SIZE_RANGE,pointSizeRange);
```

Now how can I get the same information in Metal? I'm assuming this is HW/System dependant hence we need to query it and keep point size constrained under that limit. Unfortunately, I was not able find Metal any API around this.

But I found this [Doc](https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-Feature-Set-Tables.pdf), which says

> Maximum size of a point primitive = 54 (For all apple devices)

Now this says it's the **the same** for older iPhones (6s/7) and for MacBooks(M1s) too? Why? Are there any optimization benefits or just H/W limitations?

Comment: I'd rather say that if you need bigger points, you should anyway go through real circle geometry, hence why Apple didn't bother supporting more even if the hardware could maybe support bigger point size.

Comment: Doesn't answer my question.